# PHP Undefined index / variables

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I'm getting an undefined index error with these variables: id, subj, mid, fin. I have defined them properly and I don't know what's wrong with my code. I think the problem is with the placement of the code where I defined those 4 variables. Please help? Thanks.

```
echo "
    <form action=editgrades.php method=post>
        ID: <input type='text' name='id' maxlength='5' size='3'>
        Subject: <input type='text' name='subj' maxlength='3' size='3'>
        Midterm: <input type='text' name='mid' maxlength='3' size='3'>
        Finals: <input type='text' name='fin' maxlength='3' size='3'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'>
    </form>
";
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "school");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "select * from studentgrades";
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
$subject = $_POST['subj'];
$midterm = $_POST['mid'];
$finals = $_POST['fin'];
$average = ($midterm + $finals) / 2;
if ($average >= 70) {
    $remarks = 'Passed';
} else {
    $remarks = 'Failed';
}
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if ($res) {
    $sql1 = "
        update studentgrades set Subject = " . $subject . ",
        Midterm = " . $midterm . ",
        Finals = " . $finals . ",
        Average = " . $average . ",
        Remarks = " . $remarks . "
        where ID = " . $id . "
    ";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);
    if ($res1) {
        echo "
            Grades updated successfully.
            <br><br>
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined index: PHP variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840314/undefined-index-php-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem - you don't check if post is set. So if you call this page before submitting a form you will have undefined indices for any $_POST var you try to call.

do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "school");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
    else{
    $sql = "select * from studentgrades";
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $subject = $_POST['subj'];
    $midterm = $_POST['mid'];
    $finals = $_POST['fin'];
    $average = ($midterm+$finals)/2;
    if($average >= 70){
    $remarks = 'Passed';
    }
    else {
    $remarks = 'Failed';
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    if ($res) {
    $sql1 = "
    update studentgrades set Subject = ".$subject.",
    Midterm = ".$midterm.",
    Finals = ".$finals.",
    Average = ".$average.",
    Remarks = ".$remarks."
    where ID = ".$id."
    ";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);
    if ($res1){
    echo "
    Grades updated successfully.
    <br><br>
    ";
    }
}
```

Although isset($_POST['id'])) can be substituted with any number of ways to verify the form was submitted.

A side note - you should probably run all of your post processing before any html is output in case you need to modify headers based on the post results. if this code needed to do something like:

```
if($id == '')
{
    header('location: /');
    exit;
}
```

it would tell you headers have already been sent and give you another error.

Comment: Whoever down voted this answer should say why it was down voted

Comment: If I had to guess I would say because I say isset($_POST['id']) and not something more abstract like !empty($_POST). Or just someone who didn't think it merited an upvote. We may never know.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to use the POST variables before the form has been submitted.

Its not complaining about the `$id`. "Undefined index" means you are trying to use a key of an array that does not exist, which in this case is the `$_POST` array.

Check the index is set before trying to use them:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
$subject = isset($_POST['subj']) ? $_POST['subj'] : null;
etc...
```

Or alternatively just turn the error reporting down (not recommended)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: **Moderator Note** There was no way to purge the non constructive comments under this answer while leaving some semblance of a conversation in tact, so all comments were purged. Please keep comments constructive, professional and on topic. Additionally, please avoid extended discussion in comments, use the chat facility for that.